# Convert series of images to video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, mencoder

I have series of images with sorted names, like 0000000354 ... 0000008591
I have tried using ffmpeg or MEncoder to convert theme. In ffmpeg the problem is this that it will operate while the names are like 0000000001 ... 00000000009 with %010d syntax.I don't know  what syntax i should use for my images names.in mencoder it will cover all images But when i play the output video it doesn't show images,I want to show every image in 5 seconds or somthing like this, any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg can't read in arbitrarily named images.  You'll have to rename them or do something clever with symlinks to get ffmpeg to take them as input.

From the man page:

> If the pattern contains "%d" or "%0Nd", the first filename of the file
>   list specified by the pattern must contain a number inclusively
>   contained between 0 and 4, all the following numbers must be
>   sequential. This limitation may be hopefully fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have:

```
img000001.jpg
....
img000140.jpg
....
img010040.jpg
....
```

To encode it into a movie using ffmpeg just use the filename pattern:

```
ffmpeg -i "img%06d.png" -vcodec libx264 -vpre ipod640 output.mp4
```